# Fetch documents from a MongoDB collection based on timestamp

Tags: mongodb, epoch

I have a MongoDB collection with documents that look like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aab91b2caa256021558f3d2"),
    "Timestamp" : "2017-11-16T14:43:07.5357785+01:00",
    "status" : 1,
    "created_at" : 1521193394,
    "updated_at" : 1521193394,
    "deleted_at" : ""
}
```

Data gets entered into the collection every 15 minutes. Using the created_at field, which is in epoch time, I would like to find a way to fetch data at the top of every hour. So for example, data is entered at `12.00 12.15 12.30 12.45 13.00 13.15 13.30 13.45 14.00`.

I would like to fetch entries from the collection that were entered at 12.00 13.00 and 14.00.

I am also open to suggestions as to whether or not using epoch time is the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using epoch time is really a good way to go.

Since you are stoing in seconds, every round hour can be divisible by 3600(seconds in hours) without remainder. You can make use of this property to find your documents.

```
db.collection.find({created_at: {$mod: [ 3600, 0 ]}});
```

According to [$mod](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/mod/) documentation, it will,

> Select documents where the value of a field divided by a divisor has
>   the specified remainder

We provided divisor as `3600` and remainder as `0`. This should give what you expect.

**To ignore seconds:**

For this condition, `mod(epoch, 3600)` should be less than 59. This query can be formed using [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) of mongo 3.6

```
db.collection.find({$expr: {$lte: [{ $mod: [ '$created_at', 3600 ] }, 59]}});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot @RaR that helped a lot, but there was a little over site on my part. Even though the entries are coming in at 12.00 for example, it may not be exactly 12.00.00 and since we are using epoch time, 12.00.00 will be different from 12.00.05 so doing it that way doesn’t fetch any records. Do you have any ideas on how to query for something like 12.00.*?

Comment: @user3010617  That can be done with $expr which is available from mongo 3.6. Which version of mongodb are you using?

Comment: Thanks a lot @RaR, this appears to work nicely when I run it against the collection, I'm using version 3.6.2. 
Just need to figure out how to translate it to something `jenssegers/laravel-mongodb` can understand

Comment: @user3010617, Just noticed, the condition should be `$lte` or `$lt` with value 60 since till 59th second, we can consider as round hour. Updated the answer to `$lte`